# Symfony - ELK - interpret json logged across Monolog

Tags: json, logstash, symfony, elastic-stack

i'm logging and analysing my logs with the ELK stack on a symfony3 application.
From the symfony application i want to log jsons object that might be a little bit deep.
Is there any way that Kibana interprets my json as a json and not a string ?

Here is an example of the way i'm logging,

```
$this->logger->notice('My log message', array(
    'foo'         => 'bar,
    'myDeepJson1' => $deepJson1,
    'myDeepJson2' => $deepJson2          
));
```

And there, my logstash.conf. I used the symfony's pattern that i found here : https://github.com/eko/docker-symfony

```
input {
    redis {
        type      => "symfony"
        db        => 1
        key       => monolog
        data_type => ['list']
        host      => "redis"
        port      => 6379
    }
}

filter {
    if [type] == "symfony" {
        grok {
            patterns_dir => "./patterns"
            match        => [ "message", "%{SYMFONY}" ]
        }
        date {
            match => [ "date", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" ]
        }
        if [log_type] == "app" {
            json {
                source => "log_context"
            }
        }
    }
}

output {
    if [type] == "symfony" {
        elasticsearch {
            hosts    => ["172.17.0.1:9201"]
            index   => "azureva-logstash"
        }
    }
}
```

Actually, enverything i'm logging is in the log_context variable, but monolog transforms the array into a json, so, my $deepJson variables are double encoded, but, there's no way to log a multidimensional array in the context...

any help would be appreciated. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the retrieved the requestJson from log_context, you have to remplace all the \" with " in order to be able to parse it with the json plugin.
You can do it with the mutate filter and its gsub option ([documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-gsub)).
After you can then parse the resulting json with the json plugin.

You can update your documentation with:

```
if [log_type] == "app" {
    json {
        source => "log_context"
    }
    mutate {
        gsub => ["requestJson", "\\"", "\""]
    }
    json {
        source => "requestJson"
        target => "requestJsonDecode"
    }
}
```

Comment: For reference: [json codec](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/2.2/plugins-codecs-json.html)

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer, but this doesn't solve my problem...
the json string is not interpreted... i'd like to be able to navigate in the json like in a table... Kibana is still showing me the field as raw json

Comment: Can you add a few log example and what you want to have in ES, please? It might help me understand your problem

Comment: Oops, I did not see the example in your question. What does it looks like in the log file?

Comment: Sorry for the looong string, the field i'd like Kibana to understand as json (and provide me an array-like access) is 'requestJson' :
http://pastebin.com/peaud07e

Comment: in the json codec's reference, i see that all the input might be json encoded in order to make it work... but this isn't what i'm sending...

Comment: Perhaps you can run the requestJson through the mutate filter with [gsub](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-gsub) to replace the \" with " (gsub => ["requestJson", "\\"", "\""])
Then you use the the [json filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json.html) on requestJson. 
That way you can get the json content of requestJson in fields in the ES document.

Comment: And to get the requestJson, you'll have to use the json filter a first time on log_context, just like you did in your configuration

Comment: I'll update my answer now that I have a better understanding of the problem

Comment: i had the feeling that i should do something like this...
and thanks, there's some progress, but is there any way that i have a view in Kibana that provides me an array access-like of my json, like in the right window of this link :
http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=c413f1d171cbd94a5ea67c8cdff596b5

Comment: Appart from the expand button ([kibana documentation])(https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/discover.html#document-data) in the discovery view, I think there aren't any other way. Kibana works more toward aggregations and counting than easy reading of one document.